# ruby yield and return exist in one method simultaneously

Tags: ruby

What is point to have `yield self` and `self` in tap method.
I think only `yield self` is enough.
The following code from Github faraday.rb

```
class Object
  def tap
    yield self
    self
  end unless Object.respond_to?(:tap)
end
```

Comment: I got the point, but **yield self** also return **self** while call tap. It is right or not?

Comment: If `yield self` is the last statement in `tap` the expression `something.tap { |x| ... }` will return the value of the block, with `return self` it will return the value of `self`, which will likely be different if the block is non-desctructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield self` passes `self` to the block `tap` is called with, whereas the `self` at the end is what `tap` returns. That's exactly the point of `tap`, using the object in a block and still being able to pass it on to the next method in the chain. Note however that if the block method is destructive, you'll pass on the modified version. Personally I try to avoid that, since I mostly use `tap` for debugging purposes.

Comment: You are actually free to modify the object within the block (assuming it has mutable state), and it will be its modified form that will be passed on to the next method in the chain.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll reword that.

Comment: @Russell: I reworded my answer so you can remove the downvote (or suggest further edits if still not satisfied).

Comment: I'm still not sure it's clear - I don't know why you say it passes on  the unmodified object at all, because it doesn't. As an example, you might use it to build up a hash with conditionals. I would give an example here but can't really post legible multiline code in a comment and don't want to post an answer.

Comment: Done. As an aside, there are lots of lovely uses of `tap`. Debugging is a good one!

Comment: I guess I always just use 1.9's `each_with_object` or `inject` (in 1.8 and 1.9) for building up hashes, never occurred to me to use `tap` for that. :-)

Comment: I used to use `inject` but found it ugly having to have the last line in the block just being the hash on its own. `each_with_object` looks perfect though!

Comment: `tap` is really useful in a multitude of scenarios with the sole purpose of avoiding temporary variables and/or explicit return value lines.  I use it lots.